# Update columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe look like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(number = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                  name1 = c("Acer laurinum", NA, "Acmella paniculata", "Acronychia cf. pedunculata", "Acronychia pedunculata", NA, "Adinandra cf. integerrima",NA),
                  name2 = c(NA, "Acer laurinum Hassk.", NA, NA, NA, "Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.", NA, "Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson"),
                  name3 = c("Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Acmella paniculata", "Acronychia cf. pedunculata", "Acronychia pedunculata",
                            "Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.", "Adinandra cf. integerrima", "Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson"))

df

  number                      name1                                name2                                name3
1      1              Acer laurinum                                 <NA>                        Acer laurinum
2      2                       <NA>                 Acer laurinum Hassk.                 Acer laurinum Hassk.
3      3         Acmella paniculata                                 <NA>                   Acmella paniculata
4      4 Acronychia cf. pedunculata                                 <NA>           Acronychia cf. pedunculata
5      5     Acronychia pedunculata                                 <NA>               Acronychia pedunculata
6      6                       <NA>     Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.     Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.
7      7  Adinandra cf. integerrima                                 <NA>            Adinandra cf. integerrima
8      8                       <NA> Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson
```

I still want to update the column `name3` based on `name2` and `name1` since hofully my conditions  make more sensen now.

First, let's look at my desired output

```
 number                      name1                                name2                                name3
1      1              Acer laurinum                                 <NA>                 Acer laurinum Hassk.
2      2                       <NA>                 Acer laurinum Hassk.                 Acer laurinum Hassk.
3      3         Acmella paniculata                                 <NA>                   Acmella paniculata
4      4 Acronychia cf. pedunculata                                 <NA>           Acronychia cf. pedunculata
5      5     Acronychia pedunculata                                 <NA>     Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.
6      6                       <NA>     Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.     Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.
7      7  Adinandra cf. integerrima                                 <NA>     Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson
8      8                       <NA> Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson
```

So, the idea is that I would like to say if `name3` matchs with `name2` (i.e. `Acer laurinum Hassk.`), and `name3` matchs with `name1` (i.e. `Acer laurinum`). All of them share the same string `Acer laurinum`. Then the character of `name3` (i.e. `Acer laurinum`) should be replaced by the name with the author part. This rule will be apply entire rows to get the updated names.

Any sugesstions for me this case?

Comment: Is the match between `name3` and `name2` for the entire column of `name2`?

Comment: Is the name2 column, if matching a name1 value in the first two "words", always preferred?

Comment: @Tjn25 yes, `name3` will contain all the value of `name2`

Comment: @JonSpring hmm... at first I think yes, but then I realized that some names like `Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson`, we have the `cf.` inside, it means that if we get the first two 'words' that would not work this case. What do you think?

Comment: if we only have `Adinandra integerrima T.Anderson` without `cf. `, then it would be very nice, but the way i am doing it here. I would like to keep them.

Comment: So you want the longest name among two that have no contradicting segments? It seems there might be a lot of edge cases you haven't given instructions about, so this looks inadequately specified. Do the matches need to be full "words" (ie spaces on either side)? What to do with ties? Is there a minimal word length to match? (ie what if there is a name1 that's just "cf." -- does that match "Acronychia cf. pedunculata" or "Adinandra cf. integerrima"?

Comment: I already narrowed spaces on either side by `trimw`. Column`name1`  does not contain single `cf.` And basically, I want the name without author part now would be replaced by the name with author part or added the author part. I did add the author part before by using `lapply`. However, something went wrong then I changed the idea of name - matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution using `agrep`.

```
# Your sample data
df1 <- data.frame(number = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                  name1 = c("Acer laurinum", NA, "Acmella paniculata", "Acronychia cf. pedunculata", "Acronychia pedunculata", NA, "Adinandra cf. integerrima",NA),
                  name2 = c(NA, "Acer laurinum Hassk.", NA, NA, NA, "Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.", NA, "Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson"),
                  name3 = c("Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Acmella paniculata", "Acronychia cf. pedunculata", "Acronychia pedunculata",
                            "Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.", "Adinandra cf. integerrima", "Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson"))



# Get the matching name with 'agrep', and save it in a vector resultmatch.
resultmatch <- NULL
for(i in df1$name1[!is.na(df1$name1)]) {
  out <- df1$name2[agrep(pattern = i, df1$name2)]
  if(length(out) == 0) out <- NA
  resultmatch <- c(resultmatch, i, out)
}
# Transform output in dataframe
resultmatch <- as.data.frame(matrix(resultmatch, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(resultmatch ) <- c("name1", "name3")

# Bind df1 (removing current column "name3") and resultmatch.
df2 <- merge(df1[,-4], resultmatch , by = "name1", all = TRUE)

# When NA in name3: there were no match. Replace the NAs with name1, then name2 (or name2, then name1, the order here doesn't matter)
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(name3 = ifelse(is.na(name3), name1, name3),
                      name3 = ifelse(is.na(name3), name2, name3)) %>%
  select(colnames(df1)) %>% arrange(number) # to reshape data to the initial form, but not necessary  

df2
```