# Sum rows with similar strings

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a `df` looks like this (Since several questions of mine were not clear then I changed to this way)

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Acmella paniculata", 
                          "Adinandra cf. integerrima", "Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson"),
                 value1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 value2 = c(2,3,4,5,6))

                         name            value1 value2
1                        Acer laurinum      1      2
2                 Acer laurinum Hassk.      2      3
3                   Acmella paniculata      3      4
4            Adinandra cf. integerrima      4      5
5 Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson      5      6
```

I would like to sum/aggregate rows based on the `name` column with the condition: If strings of two rows are similar, then they must be summed. And importantly, the name resulted by the aggregation would be the name with Author part. In the real data, the names located in different rows, then I just made an example here to show my expectation. Anyone help me,please?

- Desired output

```
 name value1 value2

1                 Acer laurinum Hassk.      3      5
2                   Acmella paniculata      3      4
3 Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson      9      11
```

Comment: I know how to sum by group, however, the point in my question is the name

Comment: Okay, fair enough, sorry. By what logic do you decide that the first two and last two are similar and  how do you decide which value is ultimately grouped by?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I would like to use the longer name `Acer laurinum Hassk.` sharing the same string with `Acer laurinum`. Since I have many cases, so we can not call directly the name.

Comment: And how do you decide similarity? Is it exact substring matching? Is it always the beginning that has to exact match?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach that is annoying me. Since I want the value sharing one, two, or even three same string would be summed up, and get the longer one (since it will contain the author part).

Comment: then you might want to read this post of mine, it havet solved it yet, that's why I changed the way I approach it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537199/update-columns-in-r?noredirect=1#comment122910341_69537199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution based on defining each row as a dynamic pattern and matching the words that occur across pairs of rows:

```
# function to automatically *escape* metacharacters:
escape.for.regex <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}

# stopwords:
stopwords <- c("cf", "and")
stopwords_pattern <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")

# initialize vectors/columns:
pattern1 <- c()
df$repeats <- NA

# for loop with stopwords to detect repeated words across turns:
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  pattern1[i-1] <- paste0("(?!", stopwords_pattern, ")(?<!\\S)(?:", paste0(escape.for.regex(unlist(str_split(trimws(df$name[i-1]), "\\s+"))), collapse = "|"), ")(?!\\S)")
  df$repeats[i] <- str_extract_all(df$name[i], pattern1[i-1])
}
```

At this point we have identified the words that get repeated from one row to the next:

```
df
                                  name value1 value2                repeats
1                        Acer laurinum      1      2                     NA
2                 Acer laurinum Hassk.      2      3         Acer, laurinum
3                   Acmella paniculata      3      4                       
4            Adinandra cf. integerrima      4      5                       
5 Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson      5      6 Adinandra, integerrima
```

Now we need to do the summing part based on these repeats:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(repeats = gsub(" ", "", sapply(repeats, toString)),
         author = str_extract(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"),
         name = trimws(str_remove(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$")),
         repeats = ifelse(repeats == "NA"|repeats == "", NA, repeats),
         repeats = ifelse(is.na(repeats), lead(repeats), repeats)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  fill(author, .direction = "up") %>%
  group_by(name, author) %>%
  summarise(across(c(value1, value2), sum)) %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(!is.na(author), paste(name, author, sep = " "), name)) %>%
  select(-author)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name                                 value1 value2
  <chr>                                 <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Acer laurinum Hassk.                      3      5
2 Acmella paniculata                        3      4
3 Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson      9     11
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhh about this, even though it takes time for me to read and learn... but it is worthy

Comment: If you need more explanation for the code do let me know...

Comment: thank you @Chris, yes sure, since `regex` is also quite new for me, but I would love to learn it.

Comment: since doing with big database, if I know more about the `regex` that would be nice to get the format to handle the data :(

Comment: Which part of the code would you like to learn about?

Comment: some parts of `regex` code. Since everytime when I read it, I think so funny :)))), and like i am reading morse code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238086/discussion-between-chris-ruehlemann-and-anh).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
LongestSuperstring <- function(x) {
  cx <- as.character(x)  # Convert to character in case of factors.
  xx <- unique(cx)  # Get only unique values in case of dupes.
  sx <- xx[rank(nchar(xx))] # Sort them by length ascending.
  matches <- outer(sx, sx, Vectorize(grepl), fixed = TRUE)  # Get substring matches.
  # Get the index of longest superstring or itself.
  sidx <- apply(apply(matches, 1, cumsum), 2, which.max) 
  sxv <- setNames(sx[sidx], sx) # Lookup from sx to to the longest superstring.
  out <- sxv[cx]  # Look up the superstring for every x
  # Convert back to factor if needed
  if (is.factor(x)) {
    out <- factor(out, levels = levels(x))
  }
  return(out)
}

df %>%
  group_by(name = LongestSuperstring(name)) %>%
  summarize(across(c(value1, value2), sum))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved here. However, since my big database is so damn complicated asking so many condiditons, then it did not work with the real one. But anw, many thanks to you.

Comment: `outer` is almost certainly the bottleneck here. (half the time is wasted because we don't care about half of the combinations). This is an extremely generic implementation. You may be able to improve the time complexity with a clever regex call to get the mapping but you know the data best, maybe Chris' solution above is sufficient in which case it's much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat radical solution based on the assumption that the only differentiating part between the paired strings is the addition of the author. If that assumption is correct then this might work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(name = trimws(str_remove(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(across(c(value1, value2), sum))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name                      value1 value2
* <chr>                      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Acer laurinum                  3      5
2 Acmella paniculata             3      4
3 Adinandra cf. integerrima      9     11
```

How the regex works:

- `(?<=\\s)`: asserts a whitespace character to the left
- `(?=.*\\.)`: asserts the occurrence of a `.`anywhere in what follows
- `[.\\w]+$`: a character class containing `.` and alphanumeric characters at the end of the string

**EDIT**:

if you want to keep your original `name` column:

```
df %>%
  mutate(author = str_extract(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"),
         name = trimws(str_remove(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  fill(author, .direction = "up") %>%
  group_by(name, author) %>%
  summarise(across(c(value1, value2), sum)) %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(!is.na(author), paste(name, author, sep = " "), name)) %>%
  select(-author)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name                                 value1 value2
  <chr>                                 <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Acer laurinum Hassk.                      3      5
2 Acmella paniculata                        3      4
3 Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson      9     11
```